# Failure to install PyMC

Tags: python, macos, 64-bit, enthought, pymc

I am running Python 2.7.3 from EPD 7.3 (Enthought Python Distribution, 64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (Maverick). The version of gfortran I am using is 4.9.0

I tried to install PyMC from building the source code:

```
python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler gfortran build
```

But it fails with exit status 1:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/pymc
compile options: '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c'
extra options: '-faltivec'
gcc: cephes/i0.c
clang: error: invalid argument '-faltivec' only allowed with 'ppc/ppc64/ppc64le'
clang: error: invalid argument '-faltivec' only allowed with 'ppc/ppc64/ppc64le'
error: Command "gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c cephes/i0.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/cephes/i0.o -faltivec" failed with exit status 1
```

I am not sure how to fix the problem. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymc/5M_9uoaZjy4

Comment: @Babu Seems that the post does not help and it is a different error..

Comment: Finally I successfully installed PyMC using a 32-bit version Enthought Canopy Python and gfortran 4.3.2.